# Insert at start function in linked list is not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the following code, I am creating a linked list but in the function, insert_at_start is only adding 5 only even after calling function again it only printing 5.

```
    from pip import main
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
              self.data = data
              self.next = next

    class linkedlist:
        def __init__(self):
              self.head = None
        def insert_at_start(self, data):
              node = Node(data, self.head)
              self.head = node
        def print(self):
              if self.head is None:
                  print("Linked List is empaty.")
                  return
              itr = self.head
              llst=" "
              while itr:
                  llst = str(itr.data) + "--->"
                  itr = itr.next
              print(llst)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
         ll = linkedlist()
         ll.insert_at_start(5)
         ll.insert_at_start(10)
         ll.insert_at_start(12)
         ll.insert_at_start(70)
         ll.print()
```

Comment: You forgot a `+` in `llst += str(itr.data) + "--->"`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @trincot ah yes! always the symbols. Thanks, it worked.

Comment: I recommend that you don't use the name "next" as it hides `next()`

Comment: Rather than adding a method `print()`, I might look at implementing `__str__()` and then only print()` from within `__main__`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `print` to be called for each node, it has to be *inside* the loop.